# HTML + CSS z-index not working

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a very annoying problem which is my z-index is not working and the div is sitting above (on the y-axis) and not on top of (on the z-axis) the other div.

This will probably be completely obvious but I cannot see a problem with my code. Can anyone spot where I am going wrong? It should be so easy but I am getting so frustrated because I cannot find a solution.

```
<style>
.greenleftarrow{
position: relative;
z-index:10;
display:block;
background:#fff url(./images/greenleftarrow.jpg) no-repeat;
left:10px;
top: 0px;
height:140px;
opacity:0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}

</style>


<body id="body1" style="position: relative; z-index:-1; height: 510px;" onload="javascript:showAndroidToast('1'); inspectLang(); getDocHeight()">
<div class="greenleftarrow"  id="greenleftarrow" ></div>
<div  style="position: relative; z-index:-1;">body body body body</div>
</body>
```

Comment: so you want the arrow on top of the div? remove position:relative on body & div, and replace position:relative to position:absolute on the arrow?

Comment: I'm not really clear what it is you're trying to achieve - can you post a live example (in jsFiddle or similar) or an image. What are you trying to position `.greenleftarrow` relative to? I'm also confused why you're applying a negative z-index to the body itself?

Comment: Well, the negative z-index was out of frustration because the initial z-index of 1 was being ignored, or so I thought. I will have to try jsFiddle for more comprehensive posting in future. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change the position of the arrow to absolute.

```
  .greenleftarrow{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:10;
  display:block;
  background:#fff url(./images/greenleftarrow.jpg) no-repeat;
  left:10px;
  top: 0px;
  height:140px;
  opacity:0.5;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
  }
```

Comment: I wish! It just disappears when I do that!!!! Is it because it is a background image?

Comment: The position absolute worked once I set the minimum width and height to the size of the background image. After all, an empty div is just that, an empty div. Stupid mistake!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use a negative top margin to move the second div upwards onto greenleftarrow:

http://jsfiddle.net/XSH2Y/

Comment: I love jsfiddle thanks for linking that to me. It is getting added to my list of favourites.

Comment: Quick question though, to use #over {
    margin-top: -140px;
} would I have to know the height of the background image in the greenleftarrow class?

Comment: Yes. If greenleftarrow only contains a background image you could just add it to the second div and give the div a min-height

Comment: Thanks for your comments a combination of yours and Pedryk helped me solve it. Set position to absolute and give the div a minimum height.